# Using $addFields as part of an update function in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out how to use the `$addFields` operation within a function I'm using to update a document. The logic to generate this field is simple enough, I just pull out the last object in an array, like so:

```
  {
    $addFields: { activeWorkflow: { $arrayElemAt: ["$workflow", -1.0] } }
  }
```

Now I need to figure out how to get this aggregation into my update function, the relevant code of which looks like this:

```
updatedDoc = await request.findOneAndUpdate(
  StaffMember,
  {
    _id: request.parameters.id
  },
  req,
  {
    new: true
  }
);
```

What I tried doing was this:

```
updatedDoc = await request.findOneAndUpdate(
  StaffMember,
  {
    _id: request.parameters.id
  },
  req,
  {
    new: true
  }
);

await request.aggregate(updatedDoc, [
  {
    $addFields: { activeWorkflow: { $arrayElemAt: ["$workflow", -1.0] } }
  }
]);
```

... but this gives me an error:

> TypeError: mongooseModelObject.aggregate is not a function

Would I use the $addFields operator with $set, like so?

```
updatedDoc = await request.findOneAndUpdate(
      StaffMember,
      {
        _id: request.parameters.id
      },
      {
        $set: {
          req,
          $addFields: { activeWorkflow: { $arrayElemAt: ["$workflow", -1.0] } }
        }
      },
      {
        new: true
      }
    );
```

How does one run an aggregation as part of a function like this? A simple example would help me understand how this needs to be done -- if indeed it can be done.

Of course, there are other ways to do this, but I'd like to take advantage of a mongo-specific way to handle this, using a mongo operation like `$addFields`. What would this look like?

By the way, the wrapper function I'm using with aggregate looks like this:

```
  async aggregate(mongooseModelObject, aggregateObject = {}) {
    try {
      return await mongooseModelObject.aggregate(aggregateObject).exec();
    } catch (err) {
      this.sendError(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can't use `aggregate` as part of an update. The only way to update the data using `$addFields` is to use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) like this:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {  $addFields: { activeWorkflow: { $arrayElemAt: ["$workflow", -1.0] } } },
    {  $out: "col" }
])
```

but this will unfortunately add `activeWorkflow` for all the documents in `col`.

For regular `.update()` you can't refer to another field so the only way to do that for single doc is use to `findOne()` to get that document, then add new field in your application logic and then use `update()` or `save()` to store that updated document (old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)).

Comment: In my use case I do want to add activeWorkflow to all documents. It's basically a field that needs to dynamically update whenever an update is made to a document in the collection. Of course each document will be different and so the result for `activeWorkflow` would be different for each document. So this would work in my use case?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from MongoDB 4.2, `findAndUpdateOne`, `updateOne`, `updateMany` can accept an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#use-an-aggregation-pipeline-for-updates) for the update.

```js
const updatedDocument = await DocumentModel.updateOne({ _id: id }, [
  {
     $set: {
       items: items,
     }
  },
  {
     $addFields: { totalItems: { $sum: '$items.quantity' } },
  }
 ],
 { new: true } // to return updated document
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.col.aggregate` won't change data in collection but `db.col.insertMany` will

```
db.temperatures.updateMany({}, [{$addFields: {"fields-name": "value"}}])
```